# spring framework の宣言的トランザクション管理ができない

Tags: java, spring

Spring Framework と MyBatis を使用してアノテーションによる
宣言的トランザクション管理を行おうとしていますが、ロールバックされません。

設定に不備があると思うのですが、何が悪いか検討がつかない状態です。
不備などありましたらご指摘してくださると助かります。

コード修正してプログラムによるトランザクション管理も試したところ、こちらは可能でした。

【pom.xml】

```xml
<!-- 省略 -->
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
<!-- 省略 -->
        <!-- MyBatis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
          <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- 省略 -->
```

【root-context.xml】

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop ="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://****.com:5432/****" />
        <property name="username" value="****" />
        <property name="password" value="****" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:com/hatak/photomap/domain/mapper/*.xml" />
        <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.hatak.photomap.domain.entity" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.hatak.photomap.domain.mapper" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

【サービスクラス】

```
@Service
public class HomeServiceImpl implements HomeService {

    @Autowired
    private MessagesMapper messagesMapper;

    @Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
    public void execute(HomeServiceDto homeServiceDto) throws Exception {

        // DB更新
        MessagesEntity entity = new MessagesEntity();
        entity.setId(13);
        entity.setMessage(homeServiceDto.getMessage());
        int count = messagesMapper.update(entity);

        // 強制ロールバック
        if (count == 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("ロールバックしてない");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

おつかれさまです。

おそらくAutoCommitが有効になっているように思われました。DataSource取得のところでCommons-DBCPを使われているようですので、defaultAutoCommit="false"のプロパティを追加してください。

Springの宣言的トランザクション定義は問題ないようです。

以上です。

Comment: A-pZさま

お返事ありがとうございます。困り果てていたところでしたので心強いです。
dataSourceに以下の1文を追加してみましたが、やはりコミットされてしまうようです。。。
> <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />

Comment: なるほど了解しました。MybatisがSpring管理下で正しく連携してないようですね。

ひとつ気になったのですが、Mybatis-Springプラグイン(バージョンは1.2.2が最新です)をお使いだと思うのですが、"https://mybatis.github.io/spring/ja/mappers.html#scan"にもありますよう、mybatis:scanで検出するのでもダメでしょうか。理由はリンク先にもありますが、他にも、https://mybatis.github.io/spring/ja/transactions.html
にもありますように、"Spring が管理するトランザクションの外側で SqlSession のデータメソッドあるいは Mapper メソッドを呼び出した場合、JDBC 接続に対する auto-commit の設定に関わらず、変更は直ちにコミットされます。"の文と、サンプルコードがあります。

Comment: はい、Mybatis-Springプラグインのバージョンは1.2.2です。こちらのページを見てMapperScannerConfigurer を使っていました。"https://mybatis.github.io/spring/ja/sample.html"
MapperScannerConfigurer を 下記に変更してみました。
<mybatis:scan base-package="com.hatak.photomap.domain.mapper" />
これでもコミットされるようです。。。プログラムによるトランザクション管理はできるたので、それとの差異に原因があるんですよね。。

Comment: すいませんhttpsが抜けていました。 https://mybatis.github.io/spring/ja/sample.html

Comment: なるほど了解です。提示していただいたSpringの設定やMybatisの設定についてはやはり問題がありませんでした。

他に問題となる可能性があるとすれば、以下が考えられます。

- Mybatisの設定が他にも存在し、そこでjdbcの設定が存在する
- PostgreSQLのJDBCドライバがお使いのPostgreSQLと適切なバージョンではない

明確な回答にならず申し訳ありません。

Comment: お返事遅くなってすいません。少しずつ調査してました。下記サイトのサンプルプロジェクト jpetstore ではロールバックできました。 http://mybatis.github.io/spring/ja/sample.html これからspring-mvc の新規プロジェクトに移植したところロールバックしませんでした。（多少弄っているので抜けがあるかも）。引き続き地道に調査はしますので、解決したらご報告だけしますね。たびたびありがとうございます。

Comment: Mybatisの設定は他に無く、PostgreSQLは9.3.5を使用しています。

Comment: 持病などで調査が遅くなってしまいました。仰る通りこの部分の設定に問題はなかったようです。フィルターを使用しているのですが、そちらの設定に誤りがあるようです。フィルターを使用しなければロールバックが確認できました。